# Magento duplicate content block

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to override the user account index template, but when I do so, the content is duplicated.

Here is my local.xml

```
<customer_account_index>
    <label>Customer My Account Dashboard</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>

    <remove name="left"/>
    <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>

    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer_account_dashboard" template="customer/account/dashboard.phtml">
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard_info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard_info" name="child_account_dashboard_info" as="childinfo" template="customer/account/dashboard/mychild.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

and my base custommer.xml

```
<customer_account translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account (All Pages)</label>
    <!--remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
    <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"/-->
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="my.account.wrapper" translate="label">
            <label>My Account Wrapper</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>my-account</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
        </block>
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
        <remove name="tags_popular"/>

    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

If I use name="content" instead of name="my.account.wrapper" to insert the content, it will not be duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my problem:
in the customer.xml there is already  in the customer_account_index handle, so I removed it from my local.xml